Making a multiple stage selector in Roblox Studio
I'm making a stage selector that you can go forward and back a stage in my Roblox Game,
but it didn't work, here's the code:
local trasferHandler = {}

local TOTAL_STAGES_IN_GAME = 10

for _, stage in pairs(workspace.Checkpoints:GetChildren()) do
    if tonumber(stage.Name) > TOTAL_STAGES_IN_GAME then
        TOTAL_STAGES_IN_GAME = tonumber(stage.Name)
    end
end

function trasferHandler.up(plr, direction)
    local tpStage = plr.TeleportedStage
    if tpStage.Value < plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value then
        tpStage.Value += 1
        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = workspace.Checkpoints[plr.TeleportedStage.Value].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3.25,0)
    elseif tpStage.Value == plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value then
        tpStage.Value = 0
        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = workspace.Checkpoints["0"].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3.25,0)
    end
end

function trasferHandler.up2(plr, direction)
    local tpStage = plr.TeleportedStage
    if tpStage.Value < plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value then
        tpStage.Value += 10
        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = workspace.Checkpoints[plr.TeleportedStage.Value].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3.25,0)
    elseif tpStage.Value == plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value then
        tpStage.Value = 0
        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = workspace.Checkpoints["0"].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3.25,0)
    end
end



function trasferHandler.down2(plr, direction)
    local tpStage = plr.TeleportedStage
    if tpStage.Value > 10 then
        tpStage.Value -= 10
        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = workspace.Checkpoints[tpStage.Value].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3.25,0)
    elseif tpStage.Value == 0 then
        tpStage.Value = plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value
        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = workspace.Checkpoints[plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3.25,0)
    end
end

return trasferHandler



i was expecting it to change the stage i was at, and somehow, it also broke the ability for me to go backwards.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please include any errors in the Developer Console or Output Window in your question along with clarifying specifics such as what the ability to go back means and how it was broken.

no errors in the output D:



local checkpoints=workspace.Checkpoints
local TOTAL_STAGES_IN_GAME=#checkpoints:children()
local function tp(player,x)
    local val=Instance.new"DoubleConstrainedValue"
    val.MaxValue=TOTAL_STAGES_IN_GAME-(checkpoints:FindFirstChild"0"and 1 or 0)
    val.MinValue=checkpoints:FindFirstChild"0"and 0 or 1
    local stage=player.leaderstats.Stage
    val.Value=stage.Value
    val.Value+=x
    stage.Value=val.Value
    local char=player.Character 
    char=char and char:move(checkpoints[stage.Value].Position)
    --player.TeleportedStage=stage.Value
end
return {
    up=function(player)
        tp(player,1)
    end,
    up2=function(player)
        tp(player,10)
    end,
    down2=function(player)
        tp(player,-10)
    end
}




didn't work, no output either

verify that the ModuleScript is being used by the appropriate ServerScript or that workspace.Checkpoints is a Model with ModelStreamingMode set to "Persistent"

nope, nothing D:
